# Delete Wordpress posts programmatically based on a meta field value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to delete WordPress post if its custom field has a certain value. "mls" is the field's id and, for example, 185897 is the value. However, if I run this script, it deletes all of my posts with given post type. I also tried 'meta_query' instead of 'meta_input', but the result is the same.

Any idea what am I missing?

```
$delete_post = array(
    'post_type'   => 'estate_property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_input'  => array(
       'mls' => 185897
    )
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $delete_post );

if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
         wp_delete_post( get_the_ID());
    }
}
```

Comment: `'meta_input'` should be `'meta_query'` for a compound search, or simply `'meta_key' `and `'meta_value'`... So when you run the WP_Query, it's finding all posts that have post type 'estate_property' and post status 'publish'. See below for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$delete_post = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,    // The number of posts to retrieve, otherwise 5
    'post_type'   => 'estate_property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'mls',
            'value' => '185897'
        )
    )
);
```

or

```
$delete_post = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,    // The number of posts to retrieve, otherwise 5
    'post_type'   => 'estate_property',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'mls',
    'meta_value' => '185897',
);
```

Does that work instead?

Comment: Note, I added 'numberposts'. WordPress will only retrieve 5 posts at a time (by default). if you want all of them, just pass along -1.

Comment: Thank you, first example you provided worked just fine! (I think there's one extra closing bracet)